# Merged letters in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

[image: Merged Letters]

Why are some letters are merged in Illustrator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In some fonts, the tittle on the 'i' in "fi" is removed. Does this have a name?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/56508/in-some-fonts-the-tittle-on-the-i-in-fi-is-removed-does-this-have-a-name)

Answer (score 11):

It's called a **[Ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature)** and is designed to aid in reading. You can customarily turn off ligatures via the **OpenType Panel** in Illustrator:

[image]

You can also select the ligature and use the **Glyph Panel** to choose a different glyph if you'd like.

Comment: My old artworks also showing same problem. How to solve this?

Comment: @Ash Same way. If the text has been outlined, you can't.